# VBA Loop WorksheetFunction.SumIf on Active Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

My code opens several .XLS files and makes an `SumIF` function with Active Workbook.
My code have an issue where I comment  `'Pmax BM`, `'Available Declaration` and `'Generation Schedule` (Column `C` `D` `E`  from print screen)

I think here is my problem `TW.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 23, 1)=` because I set an entire range with the results of SumIf, and that's why i have the same results in that range.`

```
Dim data As Date
Dim rng As Range
Dim TW As Worksheet: Set TW = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Centralizator Lunar")

i = 2
j = 20
StrFile = ThisWorkbook.Path
StrFile = Dir(StrFile & "\*INT2*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        TW_P = ThisWorkbook.Path
        myfile = TW_P & "\" & StrFile
        Set AWb = Workbooks.Open(myfile)
        data = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 10)
        nr_AWb = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        'Data
        TW.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 23, 1)) = data

        'Pmax BM
        TW.Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i + 23, 3)) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D20:D" & nr_AWb), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N20:N" & nr_AWb))

        'Available Declaration
        TW.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i + 23, 4)) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D20:D" & nr_AWb), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I20:I" & nr_AWb))

        'Generation Schedule
        TW.Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i + 23, 5)) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D20:D" & nr_AWb), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H20:H" & nr_AWb))

    i = i + 24
    j = j + 1


 StrFile = Dir
ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are asking, but have made some changes to your code which may address your problem (adding sheet references to ranges):

```
Dim data As Date
Dim rng As Range
Dim TW As Worksheet: Set TW = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Centralizator Lunar")

i = 2
j = 20
StrFile = ThisWorkbook.Path
StrFile = Dir(StrFile & "\*INT2*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        TW_P = ThisWorkbook.Path
        myfile = TW_P & "\" & StrFile
        Set AWb = Workbooks.Open(myfile)
        data = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 10)
        nr_AWb = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        'Data
        TW.Range(TW.Cells(i, 1), TW.Cells(i + 23, 1)) = data

        'Pmax BM
        TW.Range(TW.Cells(i, 3), TW.Cells(i + 23, 3)) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D20:D" & nr_AWb), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("N20:N" & nr_AWb))

        'Available Declaration
        TW.Range(TW.Cells(i, 4), TW.Cells(i + 23, 4)) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D20:D" & nr_AWb), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I20:I" & nr_AWb))

        'Generation Schedule
        TW.Range(TW.Cells(i, 5), TW.Cells(i + 23, 5)) = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D20:D" & nr_AWb), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4), _
                    AWb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H20:H" & nr_AWb))
        i = i + 24
        j = j + 1
        StrFile = Dir
        ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Loop
```

Comment: Hi, My question is why `j` from `.Cells(j, 4)` have always the value `20` ? because here starts the issue.

Comment: `j` is initialised as 20 so presumably your loop only runs once?

Comment: No, I run in my exemple 5 times because i have 5 files in my folder

Comment: If `j` never changes from 20 how can your loop be running five times when you have a line `j = j + 1`? Have you stepped through your code using F8 or set a breakpoint?

Comment: I stepped now, and it seems `j` take values corectly, but i don't know where is the issue

Comment: i think here is my problem `Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 23, 1)=` because i set an entire range with the results of `SumIf`, and that's why i have the same results in that range.

Comment: For one thing, you haven't updated with my correction. For another, you need to explain what you are trying to achieve. I'm lost.